# Weather forecast printing

Tags: c#

I receive a weather forecast for 5 days, but in 3 hours intervals.
This classes represent the weather forecast:

```
public class Forecast : ILocation
{
    [JsonIgnore()]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore()]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("list")]
    public IList<WeatherTimePoint> TimePoints { get; set; }
}
public class WeatherTimePoint
{
    [JsonProperty("dt")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnixTimeStampConverter))]
    public DateTime TimePoint { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("main")]
    public ClimaticData ClimaticData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("weather")]
    public IList<Weather> Weather { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("wind")]
    public Wind Wind { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore()]
    public Units Units { get; set; }
}
```

This method prints the forecast:

```
 static void PrintForecast(Forecast forecast, int days)
    {
        days = days > 5 ? 5 : days;
        DateTime printDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
        {
            printDate = printDate.AddDays(1);
            ChangeColor(ConsoleColor.Magenta);
            Console.WriteLine("== Day {0} ==", printDate.ToLongDateString());

            var timePointsDuringtDay = forecast.TimePoints.Where((weatherTimePoint) => weatherTimePoint.TimePoint.Date == printDate);
            for(int hour = 6; hour  <= 21 ; hour = hour + 3)
            {
                var weatherAtHour = timePointsDuringtDay.SingleOrDefault((weatherTimePoint) => weatherTimePoint.TimePoint.Hour == hour);
                if (weatherAtHour != null)
                {
                    ChangeColor(ConsoleColor.DarkCyan);
                    Console.Write("{0}/", hour);
                    ChangeColor(ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
                    Console.Write("{0}({1})/",weatherAtHour.Weather[0].Condition, weatherAtHour.Weather[0].Description);
                    ChangeColor(ConsoleColor.Red);
                    Console.Write("{0}{1}",weatherAtHour.ClimaticData.Temperature, UnitsHelper.GetUnit(forecast.Units, UnitsHelper.WeatherField.Temperature));
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }   
            }
            ChangeColor(ConsoleColor.White);
            Console.WriteLine("Average humidity:{0}%", timePointsDuringtDay.Average((weatherTimePoint) => weatherTimePoint.ClimaticData.Humidity));
            Console.WriteLine("Average pressure:{0} hPa", timePointsDuringtDay.Average((weatherTimePoint) => weatherTimePoint.ClimaticData.Pressure));
        }
    }
```

I thought it's quite unreadable. I am searching for any suggestion to improve the printing method. (ILocation is just a interface, that defines city and country properties. This is irrelevant for this method ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a few lines create a `Style` enum first:

```
enum Style 
{
    Header,
    Hour,
    Condition,
    Temperature
}
```

Then assign each style a color:

```
static Dictionary<Style, ConsoleColor> _styles = new Dictionary<Style, ConsoleColor>
{
    [Style.Header] = ConsoleColor.Magenta,
    ...
}
```

Use overloading to encapsulate the styling logic like this:

```
private static void Print(Style style, string format, params object[] args)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = _styles[style];
    Console.Write(format, args);
    Console.ResetColor();   
}

private static void PrintLine(Style style, string format, params object[] args)
{
    Print(style, format, args);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I think it's a good idea to stick to the `Print` & `PrintLine` convention like the console does it.

Then you can turn this:

> ```
>  ChangeColor(ConsoleColor.Magenta);
>  Console.WriteLine("== Day {0} ==", printDate.ToLongDateString());
> ```

into:

```
Print(Style.Header, "== Day {0} ==", printDate.ToLongDateString());
```

You can go even further and create a special method called `PrintHeader` and do all the magic there like so:

```
PrintHeader(printDate)
{
    Print(Style.Header, "== Day {0} ==", printDate.ToLongDateString());
}
```

This way your printing becomes even cleaner and you can manipulate the header separately.

The same applies for other cases.

---

> ```
>  DateTime printDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
>  for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
>  {
>      printDate = printDate.AddDays(1);
>      ...
>  }
> ```

I would remove the helper above the loop and write:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
 {
     var printDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(i + 1);
     ...
 }
```

**Magic numbers**

You should replace all those `5`, `6`, `21` etc with constants and give them proper names. I have no idea what they mean. You in few week will wonder too why such numbers.

---

> ```
>  if (weatherAtHour != null)    {
>  }
> ```

make it

```
if (weatherAtHour == null) { continue; }
```

to reduce nesting.

---

**`for (int hour = 6; hour <= 21; hour = hour + 3)`**

I would encapsulate this logic in a method like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Hours()
{
    for (int hour = 6; hour <= 21; hour = hour + 3)
    {
        yield return hour;
    }
}
```

Then in your weather print you can use link with ease:

```
var weathersAtHour = 
    Hours()
    .Select(hour => timePointsDuringtDay.SingleOrDefault(weatherTimePoint => weatherTimePoint.TimePoint.Hour == hour))
    .Where(x => x != null);

foreach (var weatherAtHour in weathersAtHour)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We're not seeing a method and we're not able to get all type information but OK. Your code doesn't look unreadable to me. The only thing I can suggest to clean up is the printing by extracting that part into a method and calling this.

This is how the `Print` method looks:

```
public static void Print(string message, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White, bool newLine = true)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.Write(message);
    if (newLine)
        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

And here's how you call it:

```
Print("My message", ConsoleColor.Yellow, false);
```

In your code, it will look like following (and in other places in your code):

```
if (weatherAtHour != null)
{
    Print(String.Format("{0}/", hour), ConsoleColor.DarkCyan, false);
    Print(String.Format("{0}({1})/",weatherAtHour.Weather[0].Condition, weatherAtHour.Weather[0].Description, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, false);
    Print(String.Format("{0}{1}", weatherAtHour.ClimaticData.Temperature, UnitsHelper.GetUnit(forecast.Units, UnitsHelper.WeatherField.Temperature)), ConsoleColor.Red);
}
```

Comment: I must say this isn't really an improvement over the orginal code. You still specfiy the color for each call. Some kind of mapping would be appropriate where you can predefine the colors for some enum or information type. The lengthy call to `UnitsHelper` inside the `Print` call isn't very pretty too.